# Can we build Carrom Board game in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flame

can we build a [carrom pool](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.miniclip.carrom) game clone in flutter?

i know about the flutter flame but i can't find any tutorial where any one build some thing like that

Comment: i think [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/19430602-how-to-create-a-2d-snake-game-in-flutter) should be help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, I would recommend that you use Forge2D together with Flame to build it since you will need some physics simulation. Forge2D is a stand-alone physics engine in Dart based on Box2D and you can utilize it in your flame project by adding [flame_forge2d](https://pub.dev/packages/flame_forge2d) to your `pubspec.yaml` file.

You can see some examples of how to use Forge2D together with Flame [here](https://github.com/flame-engine/flame/tree/main/packages/flame_forge2d/example).